# What shoud I change . RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I am writing functionnal tests with Selenium Python using Pycharm. I am following the Page Object Pattern and I am using PageFactory as well.
I am following the official doc examples(see https://selenium-page-factory.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and https://www.browserstack.com/guide/page-object-model-in-selenium-python)
I am trying to log in the website but I got a **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison** Exception.
I tried to set the recursion depth limit to 1500(the default value was 1000).But I still have the error.
I am pretty new to python and do not really understand the recursive functions.
Could you please tell me where I am wrong.
Here is my test_book.py where my functionnal tests run.

```
from src.pages.sign_up_page import SignUpPage
import sys
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import time


class TestLogin(unittest.TestCase):
  def testLog(self):
    print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://pubpp-developers.myriadgroup.mobi/login")
    time.sleep(10)
    user = SignInPage(driver)
    user.enter_username()
    user.enter_password()
    user.click_login_btn()
if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
```

Here is my sign_up_page.py in the src.

```
from seleniumpagefactory.Pagefactory import PageFactory


class SignInPage(PageFactory):
   def __init__(self, driver):
     self.driver = driver

   locators = {
    "mail": ("ID", "userEmail"),
    "pwd": ("ID", "password"),
    "login_btn" : ("CLASS", "customStyle__ButtonDefault___1k2JQ btn btn 
    btn-primary")
   }

   def enter_username(self):
     self.mail.set_text('address@gmail.com\n')

   def enter_password(self):
      self.pwd.set_text('abcdef123\n')
   
   def click_login_btn(self):
      self.login_btn.click_button()
```

Here is the error now (I've understood that my first field is not yet visible, that' s why it throwed the exception, I am trying to fix it, if you have any suggestions to do so, I am all ears):

```
   PS D:\POM> pytest
   =============== test session starts ======================== 
   platform win32 -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
   rootdir: D:\POM                                            
   collected 1 item

   test\test_book.py 
   DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52427/devtools/browser/a42cabce- 
   f40d-44fe-bf1d-83e5c147847b
   
   F                                                                                                                              
   [100%]
   ================================  FAILURES  =====================
   TestLogin.testLog 
   __________________________________________________________________

   self = <test.test_book.TestLogin testMethod=testLog>

   def testLog(self):
          driver = webdriver.Chrome()
          driver.get("https://pubpp-developers.myriadgroup.mobi/login")
           time.sleep(10)
           user = SignInPage(driver)
   >       user.enter_username()

  test\test_book.py:14:
  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ 
  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
  src\pages\sign_in_page.py:15: in enter_username
  self.user_name.set_text('address@gmail@gmail.com\n')
  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

  self = <src.pages.sign_in_page.SignInPage object at 
  0x00000217ED1C9570>, loc = 'user_name'

  def __getattr__(self, loc):

    if self.mobile_test == True:
        if loc in self.locators.keys():
            element = 
    self.find_element_by_accessibility_id(self.locators[loc][1])
            return element
    else:
        if loc in self.locators.keys():
            locator = (self.TYPE_OF_LOCATORS[self.locators[loc] 
    [0].lower()], self.locators[loc][1])
            try:
                element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 
     self.timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator)
                )
             except (StaleElementReferenceException, 
             NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException) as e:
                raise Exception(
                    "An exception of type " + type(e).__name__ +
                    " occurred. With Element -: " + loc +
                    " - locator: (" + locator[0] + ", " + locator[1] + 
             ")"
                )

             element = self.get_web_element(*locator)
             element._locator = locator
             return element
        >       return super().__getattr__(loc)
        E       AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 
        '__getattr__'

        C:\Python310\lib\site- 
        packages\seleniumpagefactory\Pagefactory.py:69: AttributeError
         =============================================================== 
         short test summary info 
         ===============================================================
       FAILED test/test_book.py::TestLogin::testLog - AttributeError: 
      'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
     ================================================================= 1 
         failed in 16.43s 
     ================================================================== 
     PS D:\POM>
```

You can find out the page Factory here : https://github.com/NayakwadiS/selenium-page-factory

Comment: This is probably an indentation error. Don't put the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block in the definition of `testlog`. Calling `unittest.main()` makes `TestLogin.testLog` get called, which invokes `unittest.main()`, which calls `TestLong.testLog`, etc.

Comment: Well the identation is correct in my  code. I made that error when copying/ pasting it on Stack Overflow
Thanks for your reactivity btw!
When it comes to the error, it tells me that it had made to many recursive execution on the line 42 of the class PageFactory.py
This class had been created by Selenium itself to help Page Object Model to intantiate object.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code and post the __actual__, __complete__ error message, not a screenshot.

Comment: Hello, it' s done!